# Do "Click to Tweet" and "Click to Post" still exist?

Tags: macos, notifications, facebook, twitter

Mountain Lion had "Click to Tweet" and "Click to Post" buttons in Notification Center if you had Twitter and Facebook configured in System Preferences>Internet Accounts. However, I can't find them. I'm using El Capitan. Did Apple remove this feature? I can't find anything on the Internet saying so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the widget. Open Notification Center, choose Edit, then drag the Social widget.

[image: Notification Center Social widget]

(The Twitter widget in the screenshot is from the Twitter app and shows tweets. That's not what you want. You don't need Twitter installed for this — Social is a system widget.)

If Twitter/Facebook doesn't show in the Social widget, make sure the Share Menu option is enabled for the account in System Preferences → Internet Accounts.

[image: System Preferences → Internet Accounts]